# How to use WHERE for custom field (alias)?

Tags: php, mysql, alias, where-clause

How do I accomplish query like so:

```
SELECT type, COUNT(name) as cnt FROM products WHERE cnt > 1 GROUP BY type
```

That query produces error `#1054 - Unknown column 'cnt' in 'where clause'`

It's because `WHERE` applies before grouping.
How can I workaround this?

Table structure:

```
id      name                type        price
123451  Park's Great Hits   Music       19.99
123452  Silly Puddy         Toy         3.99
123453  Playstation         Toy         89.95
123454  Men's T-Shirt       Clothing    32.50
123455  Blouse              Clothing    34.97
123456  Electronica 2002    Music       3.99
123457  Country Tunes       Music       21.55
123458  Watermelon          Food        8.73
```

Table structure borrowed from http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlcount.php for simplicity.

Comment: You can't use a field alias in a where clause

Comment: COUNT(name) will **always** give a result greater than zero because the column `name` is not nullable (according to the page you linked to). So your WHERE/HAVING clause has absolutely no effect.

Comment: Yeah, actually its ment to be 1. Still, evereone understands the problem :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use `HAVING` clause to filter the records resulting from aggregated query:

```
SELECT type, COUNT(name) as cnt FROM products GROUP BY type HAVING cnt > 0;
```